# How to save xml-file via JFileChooser

Tags: java

I have a jdom-generated XML and a Jfilechooser in a seperated method. How do I save the generated xml-file via this Filechooser?

The SaveAs-method so far:

```
public static void saveAsDialog(){
String path;
String filename;

FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter ("GPX-File","GPX");
JFileChooser saveas = new JFileChooser();
saveas.setDialogTitle("Save as ...");
saveas.setFileFilter((javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter) filter);


int userSelection = saveas.showSaveDialog(saveas);
if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveas.getSelectedFile()+".gpx");
        path=saveas.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        filename=saveas.getSelectedFile().getName();
        System.out.println(path + filename);

        fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

You're not actually writing anything before you close the `FileWriter`. Use `fw.write()`.

```
public static void saveAsDialog(String fileContent){
    // your code

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveas.getSelectedFile()+".gpx");
    fw.write(fileContent)

    fw.close();
```

---

Looks like you found this code from somewhere.

Change `gpx` to `xml` in `FileNameExtensionFilter` and `FileWriter` constructors.

Comment: no the saved file is empty while the console prints the well-formed gpx with its namespaces